# Performance of finding max partition of hive table

Tags: sql, hive

Now, I have a hive table partitioned by `dt`, `dt` is the date string. This table also has a field `col`, value of which is equal to `dt`. Do those two sqls have any difference in performance?

SQL1:

`select max(dt) from test_table`

SQL2:

`select max(col) from test_table`

Answer (score -1):

There won't be any difference if the datatype and record are similar for both case.

But if the query contains where clause with partitioned value then performance will be faster as partitioned table is going to scan only specific partition not entire table.

Comment: @Downvoter - Could you please justify why it is downvoted ??